# problem with sending a DM from a Discord bot to a member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

so when i try and run this code

```
@client.command()
async def message(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, message=None):
    message = "hello"
    embed = discord.Embed(title=message)
    await user.send(embed= embed)
```

which is supposed to send a DM to a member from my server
it doesn't work even though i enabled all intents in the script, and it doesn't show any error
the bot works like always except the part of sending a DM to a member

it's supposed to show an embed message with the title being'hello'

Comment: Why do you set `message='hello'` but also as a `None` argument? Also make sure the member actually has their direct messages open (*Even though this should show an error if that's not the case*)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you have provided doesnt make sense you are setting the message to none and then setting it to hello
here is the correct code

```py
@client.command()
async def message(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, message=""):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=message)
    await user.send(embed= embed)
```

example message

```
!message @YourDiscord Hello
```

with ! being the prefix and YourDiscord being your name

Comment: thank you so much for considering my question and answering it
it didn't work at first (the code you corrected) but after looking at it for some time i figured out that the actual problem was that there was an event i had on my bot's scripts which was interfering with the job of this command 
and that event is which i suppose you know is on_message()
i published my problem and i really need help to separate every command from this event
it seems that every command i have on my script doesn't work because of it

Comment: So what I think is happening in your code is that the on_message() is trying to read from the bot itself so it goes into an infinite loop and the program realizes that and shuts it down

Comment: So you can probably just add something like ```python
 if message.author == bot:pass
```

Comment: I cant really tell if that is the real situation here if you could provide the @on_message() code that would help alot